# Sorting Breeze navigation properties

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

How do I go about sorting a set of entities in a breeze entity? For example if I have an order with many items, how do I sort the items by orderDate?

```
    <div databind="ko with: order">
           <ol databind="foreach: items">
              <li/>
           </ol>
    </div>
```

Also, I can't use items.sort() in the data-bind, because I am making the list items sortable. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDYQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Frniemeyer%2Fknockout-sortable&ei=8BJ3UaXZMMGG2wW5yoGQCw&usg=AFQjCNFnjZ_6ths9dl_UW9BpJkFO3Yi6kA&sig2=swWZW7Rq6IqAcIX2-2Cl6w&bvm=bv.45580626,d.b2I**strong text**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the short answer is "you can't". The Breeze entity properties are simple, unordered ObservableArrays because they are part of the model.

What you want to achieve is a UI effect ... which, strictly speaking, does not belong in the model. The model is supposed to be UI independent. If the Order data are stored in a SQL database, the sequence of the Order's items is strictly undefined there.

Enough theory. You have work to do. What might I do?  One of two things

#### 1) Use an OrderViewModel

"OrderViewModel" is an "ItemViewModel" which is a wrapper around a model object that has "special powers" in support of a view. The OrderViewModel can expose its wrapped Order object for binding most of its properties. But when you need something special ... such as your sorted "items" ... you create a KO property **on the OrderViewModel** for display purposes ... call it "sortableItems" and bind to THAT in your view.

Here's a simplistic, pseudo-code implementation:

```
app.OrderViewModel = function(order) {
   this.order = order;
   this.sortableItems = ko.observableArray();

   this.resetSortableItems();
}

app.OrderViewModel.prototype.resetSortableItems() {
    // (re)initialize with copy of the items
    this.sortableItems(this.order.items().slice(0));
    // maybe some ordering logic here?
}
```

Your "sortableItems" covers the inner `Order.items` in the manner that you intended; it would be sortable, perhaps by means of the KO-Sortable feature to which you referred.

The hard part (not shown) is keeping it in sync with the inner `Order.items` property **when items are added or removed**. Remember the inner `Order.items` property is the real source of truth. Maybe you're luck and in complete command of whatever can add/remove items; then you can just call the `resetSortableItems` method when those changes occur.

This is as far as I can take you.

#### 2) Extend the Order entity with Order.sortableItems

Maybe you've decided not to be such a purist. You're willing to modify the model entity to make it play well with your UI. So you add that KO-Sortable property that I just described ... but add it to the `Order` entity [in a Custom Initializer](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/extending-entities) rather than to an OrderViewModel.

This may simplify things for you. On the other hand, you've (a) polluted the Order entity with UI concerns and (b) limited yourself to a single sort of the items which would apply to all views that reference a given Order. To (a) you may say "*who cares?*" (I do it all the time). But (b) may be a problem ... in which case you go back to the OrderViewModel for maximum flexibility.

Comment: Found this answer looking for my issue with Angular and Breeze where the database does store an Order field for a navigation collection of entities. I don't see how you can get around not crossing over the UI and the DB if the user can customize the order of a list. Think of a lookup list. Have to store that order somewhere.  With that said, I'm having the same issue. I've even adjust the API to send back the items in the correct order but Breeze still just seems to randomly list them.  I'm still trying to digest your solution here to make sense. I don't need to extend the entity it has order.

Comment: Part 2: I'm also not clear on your OrderViewModel. Maybe because I'm using angular and have not used KO.

Comment: The use of an "item view model" such as the proposed `OrderViewModel` is a general approach that does not depend upon KO. The point of this particular ViewModel is to enable you to manage who you present the related entities independent of the way they are stored in the navigation property array ... where order is not defined.

Comment: Please understand that the order of entities in a Breeze entity navigation property array is always undefined. The presumption is that order does not matter *from a business object perspective*. It  may well matter from a UI perspective in which case you cannot present the navigation property array directly but must rather present it indirectly through some other means such as the suggested  ViewModel or by using an Angular filter to sort the presented array.

Comment: @Mastro if you are using angular, you can use a filter: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33636199/150342

Comment: Using a sortable library has caused us so much pain in the past. I highly recommend *not* to expose navigation properties to a sortable component. The reason being, when you sort out elements, most sortable libraries will perform slicing on the array and moving things around and sometimes, breezejs will intercept such a slice and will think the item has been deleted which isn't the case. Going the VM way is definitely best although it requires some coding.