# Ordering Breeze Navigation Collection on an Entity with AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, breeze

This is vary similar, [Sorting Breeze navigation properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180592/sorting-breeze-navigation-properties) except I don't really understand the answer if it does apply. I posted for clarification.

I have a complex object called **MasterTimeline**

- **MasterTimeline**

  - -Which has a collection of **MasterPhases**

    - Which has a collection of **MasterMilestones**. (side not Milestones also have a collection of Tasks with an order)

Here is json

```
    [
  {
    "$id": "1",
    "Id": 6,
    "Name": "New Construction",
    "MasterPhases": [
      {
        "$id": "2",
        "Id": 19,
        "Name": "Phase 1",
        "MasterTimelineId": 6,
        "Order": 1,
        "MasterMilestones": [
          {
            "$id": "3",
            "Id": 97,
            "Name": "Milestone 1",
            "MasterPhaseId": 19,
            "Order": 1,
            "MasterPhase": {
              "$ref": "2"
            }
          },
          {
            "$id": "6",
            "Id": 98,
            "Name": "Milestone 2",
            "MasterPhaseId": 19,
            "Order": 2,
            "MasterPhase": {
              "$ref": "2"
            }
      },
      {
        "$id": "11",
        "Id": 20,
        "Name": "Phase 2",
        "MasterTimelineId": 6,
        "Order": 2,
        "MasterMilestones": [
          {
            "$id": "12",
            "Id": 99,
            "Name": "Milestone 1",
            "MasterPhaseId": 20,
            "Order": 1,
            "MasterPhase": {
              "$ref": "11"
            }
          },
          {
            "$id": "17",
            "Id": 100,
            "Name": "Milestone 2",
            "MasterPhaseId": 20,
            "Order": 3,
            "MasterPhase": {
              "$ref": "11"
            }
          }
        "MasterTimeline": {
          "$ref": "1"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Phases and Milestones both have a client configured Order property as they are part of a timeline and have to be set in the desired order. So here UI and the model overlap.

Using angular and breeze I get the timeline and loop through the phases.

- ng-repeat=*phase* in **timeline**.*phases*
- Then for each phases I loop through the milestones

  - ng-repeat=*milestone* in **phase**.*milestones*

**Problem:**
The problem is I can't figure out how to order the phases or the milestones based on their order property. It seems just random. Even though in the API I've put an order on all the methods regarding these objects.

**What I tried:**
What I did try was to use Breeze to get all Phases based on the timeline, then for each phase get the milestones, the code seemed to work but then I was getting angular errors that the uri was too long and chrome would just hang and fill the console up with errors about uri being too long.

---

**Adding some Code as Requested:**
*Note: All this works except I can order the Phases or Milestones*

Web API Methods:

```
[BreezeQueryable(MaxExpansionDepth = 4)]
    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<MasterTimeline> MasterTimelines()
    {
        return _contextProvider.QueryAll<MasterTimeline>();
    }

    [BreezeQueryable(MaxExpansionDepth = 3)]
    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<MasterMilestone> MasterMilestones()
    {
        return _contextProvider.QueryAll<MasterMilestone>().OrderBy(x => x.MasterPhaseId).ThenBy(x => x.Order);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<MasterMilestoneTask> MasterMilestoneTasks()
    {
        return _contextProvider.QueryAll<MasterMilestoneTask>().OrderBy(x => x.MasterMilestoneId).ThenBy(x => x.Order);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<MasterPhase> MasterPhases()
    {
        return _contextProvider.QueryAll<MasterPhase>().OrderBy(x => x.Order);
    }
```

**Angular MasterTimeline Repository with Breeze**

```
function getTimelines() {
    var timelines = {};
    return EntityQuery.from(controllerMethodName)
                 .expand("masterPhases, masterPhases.masterMilestones, masterPhases.masterMilestones.masterMilestoneTasks")
                 //.orderBy(orderBy)
                 .using(self.manager).execute()
                 .then(querySucceeded, self._queryFailed);

function querySucceeded(data) {
                timelines = data.results;
                return timelines;
            }
}
```

**Page Controller where I list Timelines (paraphrased)**

```
    var vm = this;
    vm.timelines {}


 function activate() {
            var promises = [getItems()];
            common.activateController(promises, controllerId)
                .then(function () {
                    log('Activated Timeline View');
                });
        }

function getItems(forceRefresh) {
            return dc.mastertimeline.getTimelines()
                .then(
                    function (data) {
                        vm.timelines = data;
                        return data;
                    });
        };

activate();
```

**Html on Page - I stripped it down as much as I could**

```
<table>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr data-ng-repeat="timeline in vm.timelines">
                                        <td>{{timeline.name}}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <table>
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th colspan="2">Phase(s)</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr data-ng-repeat="phase in vm.masterPhases">
                                                        <td><strong>{{phase.name}} (Order: {{phase.order}})</strong></td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <table>
                                                                <thead>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <th colspan="2">Milestone(s)</th>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </thead>
                                                                <tbody>
                                                                    <tr data-ng-repeat="milestone in phase.masterMilestones">
                                                                        <td>{{milestone.name}} (Order: {{milestone.order}})</td>
                                                                        <td>

                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

Comment: You don't have any relevant Breeze nor Angular code in your question to help you figure out what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Do I need it? is it possible? Feel like if I add all the code, it's gonna make my question convoluted but I'll try.

Comment: It seems impossible to help debug a problem without any relevant code, so yes I would suggest to post the minimal amount of code necessary to reproduce it.

Comment: Ok added as much as possible and stripped it down. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Few quick notes - //.orderBy(orderBy) <- What is the value of orderBy?  In your controller why are you setting the value of vm.timelines to a function that it in itself sets itself to a value?  It may be a pattern I am not familiar with but just seems like you are having a problem with recursivity and that seems recursive.

Comment: //.orderBy(orderBy) the value is "name" to order the Timelines, but I have that commented out. I tried "masterPhases.order, masterPhases.masterMilestones.order" but that gives me error about not being a single value since it's a collection.  The pattern is from John Papa's HotTowel SPA setup, it's using a repo pattern, I don't really have it setup like the code I put, it kind of represents the same thing though.  I'll update code so it's more accurate. that function is really standalone and run on load and sets the scope value. I'll update code example to show it

Answer (score 1):

**The Answer:**

Ignore everything below unless you can't use this solution, but was so simple as link (Zelda?) pointed out.

**Other Solutions**

Ok after days of trying different ways.

Found a solution that works.

Short version, after getting the data back from Breeze I pull out the child entity collections  into their own js array and sort them. No idea why I can't just do this in the object itself, would make it so much easier.

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="timeline in vm.timelines">
```

**1st Level Children Before:**

```
    <tr data-ng-repeat="phase in vm.timeline.masterPhases">

function getItems(forceRefresh) {
                return dc.mastertimeline.getTimelines()
                    .then(
                        function (data) {
                            vm.timelines = data;
                            return data;
                        });
            };
```

**1st Level Children After:**

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="phase in vm.masterPhases">

function getItems(forceRefresh) {
                return dc.mastertimeline.getTimelines()
                    .then(
                        function (data) {
                            vm.timelines = data;
                            vm.masterPhases = vm.timelines[0].masterPhases;
                            vm.masterPhases.sort(function (a, b) { return a.order - b.order; });
                            return data;
                        });
            };
```

Then to get the sub-level of Milestones

**2nd Level Children Before:**

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="milestone in phase.masterMilestones">
```

**2nd Level Children After:**

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="milestone in vm.getMasterMilestones(phase.id)">

function getMasterMilestones(phaseId) {
            var phase = vm.masterPhases.filter(function(obj) {
                return (obj.id === phaseId);
            });
            var milestones = phase[0].masterMilestones;
            return milestones.sort(function(a, b) { return a.order - b.order; });
        }
```

Not sure if this is the best way but it works. Would be nice if BreezeJs could just allow sorting on the children navigation collections.

---

**UPDATE: Even better solution** Realized I didn't need to filter, I can just send in the child property right into the function.

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="timeline in vm.timelines">
```

**1st Level**

```
 <tr data-ng-repeat="phase in vm.getMasterPhases(timeline.masterPhases)">

function getMasterPhases(phases) {
            return phases.sort(function (a, b) { return a.order - b.order; });
        }
```

**2nd Level**

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="milestone in vm.getMasterMilestones(phase.masterMilestones)">

function getMasterMilestones(milestones) {
            return milestones.sort(function(a, b) { return a.order - b.order; });
        }
```

Comment: Question: what about angularjs' `orderBy`? [orderBy docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

Comment: You are right, I was able to use that and get it working. Should post as answer, not sure why no one else suggested that idea

Comment: If you achieved a solution with `orderBy` you could answer the question yourself, including the working code. It would definitely be better than my answer without code :) even if it should be as easy as `phase in vm.timeline.masterPhases | orderBy:'Order'`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it using an angularjs filter:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="phase in vm.masterPhases | orderBy:'Order'">

<tr data-ng-repeat="milestone in phase.masterMilestones | orderBy:'Order'">
```

Reference:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy